# CSS center a div within a div

Tags: css, css-float

Stupid question, but I can't seem to figure this out.

I want the button that says: Get More Clients (underneath the computer on the right-hand side), to be centered underneath the computer.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Thanks.

Here's the URL: http://www.sanfranciscocriminaldefenseattorney.net/

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/unknown601/ob3o2cmq/)

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="c2">
<div class="sidebar sidebar-primary theme-info-sidebar">
<div class="text_box">
<div class="gsb">
<div class="get_started">
<a class="button3" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=http://themedy.com/themes/grind/&p[title]=Grind - A child theme for Thesis and Genesis&p[images][0]=http://themedy.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/grind-demo-header.jpg&p[summary]=">Get More Clients</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
columns > .c2 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sidebar {
    display: inline;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
.gsb {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.get_started {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.get_started .button3:before {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 7px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.get_started .button3 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2d609b;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: none;
    width: 80%;
}
.button3 {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background-color: #cd3333;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 4px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 28px;
    padding: 1rem 2.25rem 0.8125rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: The live example looks like it already is centered. Perhaps you can post an image of what you're aiming for.

Comment: it's perfectly centered for me, either you mean something else or maybe you're seeing a cached version

Comment: Please look at it again. I adjusted the % so u can see it's not centered.

Comment: Have you checked css-trick? css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/ I add more comments when I get to my computer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you want the button center aligned at lower screen widths because on a desktop it looks fine; it only appears skewed at lower breakpoints. The best way to do that is:

```
.get_started {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I would have NEVER figured that out.  Thanks cdx!

Comment: Do you do any freelance work?  If so, send me your contact info.  Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help. You can find my website from my profile. My email address is in the footer of the site. Also please remember to accept the answer if it's the best solution.

Comment: That's a simple way to do it

Answer (score 3):

There seem be an 80% width on button `.get_started .button3`

Below should do the job:

```
.get_started {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}
... some more styles ...
.get_started .button3 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2d609b;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: none;
    /*width: 80%;*/
    width:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply this CSS to a inner div:

```
#inner {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/unknown601/bs3t3j4j/3/)

Comment: I tried adding that to .gsb, but it didn't work.  You mean create another DIV,put it inside .gsb?

Comment: @user3117275, this example is the basic centering `div` inside a `div`,it's nice :)

Comment: Thanks i try to keep my example simple so people just starting to learn CSS can understand it easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
.get_started{width: 100%;
margin: 0px auto;
text-align: center;}
.get_started .button3{background: none repeat scroll 0px 0px #2D609B;
font-size: 18px;
text-align: center;
text-transform: none;
width: 40%;
margin: 0px auto;}
```

this code allows you to use any width you want, at the time I checked you had 40%, so you can change depending on your needs